# How to update the count in the navigation header right when a new Subscription is received?

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-navigation

i am using graphql subscription to get updates when new user is created, everything is working fine, i am receiving the updates, but i am unable to update the notification count in the navigation header from render method.

```
class ContactsList extends Component {

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {

        headerRight: (
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={{ marginEnd: 5 }}>
                    <Icon.Button
                        name="bell"
                        backgroundColor="#3b5998"
                        onPress={() => alert('Bell Pressed!!')}>

                    **//i want update the count here when new contact is created** 
                    </Icon.Button>
                </View>
            </View>

        ),
    };
};
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Subscription
                subscription={NEW_NOTIFICATION_SUBSCRIPTION}
                variables={{ token: this.state.golbalDashboardToken }} >
                {({ data, loading }) => {
                    if (loading) {
                        // alert('Loading Subcription');
                        return <Text>Loading Subscription</Text>
                    }
                    if (data) {

                        **// when new contact is created i will receive the data her**


                    }

                }
                }  
            </Subscription>
        </View
      );

}
}
```

I will receive the data inside the Subcription tag when new user is created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (data && data !== oldData) {

     **// when new contact is created i will receive the data her**
     this.props.navigation.setParams({ data }); // << this
 }
```

**in navigationOptions**

```
<Icon.Button
          name="bell"
          backgroundColor="#3b5998"
          onPress={() => alert('Bell Pressed!!')}>

          **//i want update the count here when new contact is created**
          const newData = navigation.getParam('data'); // this
 </Icon.Button>
```

Comment: The component re rendering infinitely.

Comment: make sure you check your new `data` is not equal to `old data` and call setParam only when new data is available ... it renders **infinitely** cause if (data) is always true .. check the edit plz

Comment: awesome its working now, after i made a small change, i.e.. using   **const newData = navigation.getParam('data');** call ouside the return method.